# Eliminar espacio con mongoose

Tags: mongoose

Me encuentro practicando con los esquemas de Mongoose. La verdad es que no sé cómo recibir el dato y desde el esquema borrar los espacios, tengo la propiedad `trim:true` pero solo me elimina los espacios al comienzo y al final.

```
contactPhone: { type: String, trim: true }
```

He intentado con `default` de la siguiente manera:

```
contactPhone: { type: String, trim: true, default: function prueba() {
        let telefono = this.contactPhone.replace(/ /g, "");
        return telefono;
    } },
```

pero me devuelve un error diciendo que no reconoce la propiedad `replace`. Lo que quisiera es que si alguien escribe `311 526 45 21` al momento de guardarlo quede `3115264521`.

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te ha sido más útil.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías antes de guardar el dato en la base de datos aplicarle esto:

```
contactPhone.split('').map(x => x !== ' ').join('')
```

Eso devuelve la cadena de números sin los espacios

Answer (score 0):

La solucion que pude encontrar si tal vez a alguien le sirve fue usar los hooks de moongose, aunque solo funciona para guardar, no para editar

```
_providerContractsSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
this.contactPhone = this.contactPhone.replace(/ /g,"");
next();
```

});

Saludos